# JavaFX: Styling a Sub Menu of a Context Menu

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, javafx-css

I'm trying to style the ContextMenu of a sub Menu of a ContextMenu. I want the background color of the sub menu to be **black.**

The code i have:

```
Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File", null,
                     new MenuItem("Open"),
                     new MenuItem("Import"));

myContextMenu.getItems.add(fileMenu);
```

**I tried:**

**1-** Adding a style class to the file Menu:

```
fileMenu.getStyleClass().add("sub-menu");
```

But that styled the File Menu Item and not the file popup context menu

**2-** Getting a hold of the fileMenu's context menu this way and adding the style class to it:

```
ContextMenu parentPopup = fileMenu.getItems().get(0).getParentPopup();
parentPopup.getStyleClass().add("sub-menu");
```

But that styled myContextMenu instead of the fileMenu's context menu.

**ORIGINAL STYLE**

[image]

**WITH METHOD 1**

[image]

**WITH METHOD 2**

[image]

## ===============================================

Verifiable Example:

**View.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxWidth="300.0" minWidth="300.0" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<children>
  <TabPane fx:id="_tabPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="300.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <tabs>
        <Tab text="Files Tab">
           <contextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                <items>
                    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                      <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open" />
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                      </items>
                    </Menu>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy">
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="danger" text="Delete" />
                </items>
              </ContextMenu>
           </contextMenu>
        </Tab>
     </tabs></TabPane>
</children>
```

**style.css**

```
.context-menu {
-fx-background-color: rgba(40, 43, 48, 1);
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-padding: 5px;
-fx-background-radius: 5px;
-fx-border-radius: 5px;
-fx-border-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.1);
-fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 0);
}
/********** Menu Iten ***********/
.menu-item {
-fx-background-radius: 5px;
}
.menu-item:hover, .menu-item:focused {
-fx-background-color: derive(rgba(37, 40, 45, 1), -20%);
}
.menu-item > .graphic-container {
-fx-padding: 0em 0.333em 0em 0em;
}
/********** LABEL ***********/
.menu-item >.label {
-fx-background-color:transparent;
-fx-padding: 0.2em 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em;
-fx-text-fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
-fx-effect: null;
-fx-font-size: 13px;
-fx-font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.menu-item:focused > .label {
-fx-text-fill: #fff;
}
/******* Critical Item *******/
.danger > .label {
-fx-text-fill: #f04747;
}
.danger:focused > .label {
-fx-text-fill: derive(#ff3434, 25%);
}
/***Menu***/
.menu {
-fx-background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: This is a little easier to assist with when provided a full [mcve], so I won't try to reproduce it locally, but just suggest here in a comment.  The MenuItem class has a `getStyleClass()` method, which returns the list of style classes for the item.  In addition to calling this: `fileMenu.getStyleClass().add("sub-menu")`, you might also try `openMenuItem.getStyleClass().add("sub-menu")` and similarly for your other menu items.  There may also be a cleaner way to accomplish this with CSS stylesheets and selectors, but I wouldn't know that off-hand.

Comment: @jewelsea
I added a verifiable example. The **fileMenu** has these style classes `[menu-item, menu]` the **openMenuItem** only has the `menu-item` style class. It appears that the menu class of the fileMenu is just its item class inside the main menu, while its menu-item class is the class for the filemenus items. There doesn't seem to be a class for the actual filemenu popup.

Comment: When i run the `getParentPopup()` method on a child of the fileMenu it returns the **main context menu** as the owner, as opposed to the **sub context menu** it's actually sitting in.